# Unity 5.1.1 error : dll is not allowed to be included or could not be found

Tags: ios, dll, unity-game-engine

I'm new to unity and upgrading one of my app using Unity 5.1.1. It was working fine with 4.6.2, but I'm getting following error after upgradation

```
ArgumentException: The Assembly UnityEditor is referenced by iGUI ('Assets/lib/igui/Runtime/iGUI.dll'). But the dll is not allowed to be included or could not be found.
UnityEditor.AssemblyHelper.AddReferencedAssembliesRecurse (System.String assemblyPath, System.Collections.Generic.List`1 alreadyFoundAssemblies, System.String[] allAssemblyPaths, System.String[] foldersToSearch, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2 cache, BuildTarget target) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/AssemblyHelper.cs:154)
UnityEditor.AssemblyHelper.AddReferencedAssembliesRecurse (System.String assemblyPath, System.Collections.Generic.List`1 alreadyFoundAssemblies, System.String[] allAssemblyPaths, System.String[] foldersToSearch, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2 cache, BuildTarget target) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/AssemblyHelper.cs:160)
UnityEditor.AssemblyHelper.FindAssembliesReferencedBy (System.String[] paths, System.String[] foldersToSearch, BuildTarget target) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/AssemblyHelper.cs:192)
UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()
```

I tried change compatibility from ".net 2.0 subset" to ".net 2.0", but that didn't worked.

Any help will be appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sounds like you'll need to get in touch with whoever developed iGUI.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem when trying to build the game including a custom DLL, although my error message has been slightly different.

```
ArgumentException: The Assembly UnityEditor is referenced by Namespace.In.MyCustom.Dll ('Assets/Dlls/MyCustom.dll'). But the dll is not allowed to be included or could not be found.
UnityEditor.AssemblyHelper.AddReferencedAssembliesRecurse (System.String assemblyPath, System.Collections.Generic.List`1 alreadyFoundAssemblies, System.String[] allAssemblyPaths, System.String[] foldersToSearch, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2 cache, BuildTarget target) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/AssemblyHelper.cs:156)
UnityEditor.AssemblyHelper.FindAssembliesReferencedBy (System.String[] paths, System.String[] foldersToSearch, BuildTarget target) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/AssemblyHelper.cs:194)
UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()
```

My DLL references *UnityEditor.dll*, which is not to be included in any distribution build of unity games.
I solved this issue by selecting MyCustom.dll in Unity and stop including it in the build process by unchecking 'Any Platform' (see picture).

[image: dll import settings]

In case you [referenced functionality of *UnityEditor.dll* in one of your GameObjects](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/316805/unityeditor-namespace-not-found.html), you might want to try [platform dependent compilation](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html).

Comment: You mister solved my problem. I changed it from 'Any' to 'Editor' only and the error was gone. Thx